# AWS CLI restrict restart of only one instance at a time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We have hub and spoke model in our AWS environment.

We are allowed to perform AWS CLI commands from our HUB instances on all other instances.

This includes Stop/Start, so we would like to restrict stop/start activity to only one instance at a time.

Comment: I don't think its possible with just CLI and IAM. You would need to develop fully custom solution for that.

Comment: What do you mean by "one instance at a time"? Do you mean only one instance can be stopped at any time? Or are you referring to rebooting an instance? Regardless, there is no in-built capability for such a function. As @Marcin says, you would need to handle this yourself by providing a 'service' through which users request the state change. Your service would then check the conditions and perform the command or not, as appropriate.